# How do you buffer items into groups in Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, observer-pattern, observable

I have an IObservable; where a property change has an entity ID and PropertyName.  I want to use this to update a database, but if multiple properties change almost simultaneously I only want to do one update for all properties of the same entity.

If this was a static IEnumerable and I was using LINQ I could simply use:

```
MyList.GroupBy(C=>C.EntityID);
```

However, the list never terminates (never calls IObserver.OnComplete).  What I want to be able to do is wait a period of time, say 1 second, group all the calls appropriately for that one second.

Ideally I would have separate counters for each EntityID and they would reset whenever a new property change was found for that EntityID.

I can't use something like Throttle because I want to handle all of the property changes, I just want to handle them together in one go.

Comment: The title and text of your question seem to be completely unrelated. Could you fix that?

Comment: Fixed, although I was also curious to know what GroupByUntil does and how it works, cause it looked like it might do what I wanted but didn't really seem to do anything when I tried testing it with different inputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
MyObservable
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .Select(MyList =>
        MyList.GroupBy(C=>C.EntityID));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229308%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method seems to do what you want. Give it the TimeSpan and it'll collapse all the messages into a list. There is also the [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212125%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method which does something similar, but I'm not entirely sure what its semantics might be.

Comment: In this case, Window would just be more complex than Buffer, since all you want is a list of things that have changed in the time period